# How to Change Orientation of Multi-Level Labels in a Vertical Excel Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, label

I have the following chart and I am not able to edit the first level of labels (membership, chapters, etc).  When I go to Format Axis -> Alignment I can only change the orientation of the second level (Metric #1, Metric #2, etc).

I'd like for the first level to be horizontal instead of vertical.  Help?

I'm using Professional Plus 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Andy Pope, Microsoft MVP [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/apply-vertical-rotate-270-degrees-format-to-multi/6cfd5992-5884-43c0-bcac-22d125cb4754):

> You can only control the alignment of the inner most set of
> multi-level axis labels.
>
> Except when you add a data table to the chart, then you have no
> control over the alignment.

One thing you can consider is to turn off the multi-level category option:

[image]

Comment: Darn, that's a shame.  Thank you!